# Is there a difference in performance loading different datatypes

Tags: performance, aws, redshift, load

Context: loading (COPY) a high volume of data to a warehouse (Redshift specifically however curious about all)

Question: Is there a performance difference in the different datatypes that I am loading? For example would loading a string of a timestamp into a text column be faster/slower than loading it directly as a timestamp?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. The disadvantages of using the wrong data type greatly outweigh any miniscule performance gains you envision.

Comment: Yes I agree, however i meant to imply that it would be done in two steps. first load then 'massage' data into what it should look like for data marts vs specifying the datatype in the load command.

Comment: Then i would say use a data type that works for the incoming data and facilitates the massaging as much as possible.

Comment: Ok. I was just curious to know if there was anything interesting to know 'under the hood', that's all. Since loading seems to be the slowest step in the pipeline.